# jQuery: Animating from a style-defined position to a class-defined position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I have some simple drag and drop functionality on a page, where you drop an element into a target area and that element will snap to its designated place within the target area. Currently I am accomplishing this with a "drop" event handler that adds a class to the element with the correct positions, and then removes the position styling that jQuery defined(to position the element while dragging). Thus the element is moved to its correct place.

However, I want to give the element a nice animation moving it from where you dropped it rather than just having it appear at the new place instantly. The problem is that jquery allows me to animate from one style to another style, or from one class to another class, but not to animate from a style to a class. I've tried doing this:

```
feature.addClass('selected');
feature.animate({
    'top': '',
    'left': '',
    'bottom': '',
    'right': ''
});
```

where "selected" contains definitions for top and left. But what that does is move the element to 0,0 (rather than animate the process of removing the styles which is what I want).

Does anyone know how I can do this? I could store the coordinates in the element data, but I want them to be defined in the CSS. Alternately, is there a way I could use Javascript to read the selected position from the CSS and store it dynamically? i.e. find out "for this element, what would be the values of top and left if I were to add the selected class".

Comment: jQuery already factors in computed styles from css...

Comment: Not sure what you mean? At the moment that the element is dropped, it has a position defined like style="top: 50px; left: 50px". I need that style to go away so that the underlying class is used instead, and I want jQuery to animate the process.

Comment: OP wants to animate the transition from where the user have dropped the element to the correct coordinates of where it supposed to land

Comment: you could try to get the selected coordinates something like $('.selected').css('top') (then left too). BUT you need a placeholder div so $('.selected') returns something. Once you know where you are supposed to go, you can do the animate. This means you need an empty div in every spot that is droppable. there are probably better ways to accomplish this

Comment: You can use `.attr("style","")` to clear any inline styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the idea @Huangism, I got it to work like so:

- Created an invisible "position tester" div
- During initialization, copied the classes from each draggable element to that div, and used it to test the position they'll be dropped to
- Stored those positions in the draggable elements
- Then, in the drop handler I update the element's style to those stored positions, allowing me to animate it

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming since you are using jQuery, you are using jQuery UI to do the drag and drop functionality.  There is an option on the $.draggable() method like so:

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({ revert: true });
```

more information from here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#revert

Comment: As best I can tell revert will only move the element back to where it was before, whereas I want to move it somewhere new.